# Automatically replace #DIV/0! with N/A

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

```
A                B         C
16,557      (1,107)        -7%
0                0      #DIV/0!
0                0      #DIV/0!
0                0      #DIV/0!
0                0      #DIV/0!
116            263        227%
(10,370)     4,629        -45%
14,989     (15,567)      -104%
```

I want to automatically replace`#DIV/0!` with `N/A`, and when I drag down in column C the numbers won't change except replacing `#DIV/0!` with `N/A`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `=IFERROR` around your formula.  Say for example A1 = 0, and B1 = 5.  If in cell C1 you enter the formula:

```
=B1/A1
```

You receive the divide by zero `#DIV/0!` error.  Simply wrap your formula

```
=IFERROR(B1/A1,"N/A")
```

You can replace the "N/A" with whatever you want the cell to say if there is an error.  I often use will often use "0" or "" for a blank cell.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=IFERROR(B1/A1,"N/A")
```